# parallel running of thread In-between the function call

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Am just started doing simple thread programming in java.on that I have a query what am doing is

> Create two thread and started parallely (eg. X thread and Y thread).Now Y thread having two methods Y() and Y(i).In x Thread am going to call the Y thread methods as Y(i).

In these what i stuck is that X thread wait until the method call finish in the Y thread but i have to run the two thread parallely.

```
public void onCreate() {
        X threadX = new X();
        Y threadY = new Y();
        threadY.setPriority(threadX.getPriority() + 1); // priority = 6
        threadX.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); // priority =l
        threadX.start();
        threadY.start();
        try {
            threadX.join();
            threadY.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

class X extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Thread x Started");
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\t value of i in Thread x : " + i);
            // if i module of 2 equal to 0 run the thread y with parameter i
            if (i%10 == 0) {
                // start the Y thread
                Y thread = new Y(i);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread x finished ");
    }
}

class Y extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {        
        System.out.println("Thread Y started");
        System.out.println("Thread Y Finished");
    }

    // execute the loop until condition fails
    Y() {
        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\tValue of i in Thread Y : " + i);
         }
    }

    // execute the loop based on input until condition fails
    Y(int x) {
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("\tValue of x in Thread Y : " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to run in parallel, then remove following block, from your code.

```
try {
        threadX.join();
        threadY.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
```

when you do threadX.join() , this statement will not return until threadX finished running.

Comment: look closely at your code, u will understand. your code is not a good example to test parallel processing of threads. Let me know if u still have any doubts.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, then please mark it as accepted answer. to mark, you can see a check sign below upvote button, click on that. Thanks

Comment: I just can't understand your answer is that you have any sample code in this concept share me it will helpful to understand.

Comment: can please explain you question again, I can't get it exactly

Comment: Thanks...Y thread = new Y(i);
thread.start();     This line execute like new thread or calling like constructor ?.  I need to run as a thread.how can  i do it?

Comment: when u do Y thread = new Y(i), it will first execute constructor Y(i) , when Y(i) is finished, it will go to next line i.e. thread.start() , now a new thread starts in parallel and run method in Y class executes

Comment: What i need is : Need to run 2 thread parallel, in certain condition thread 1 have to pass a value to 2nd thread but both thread 1 and 2 has to run parallel.

Comment: after passing a value to Y, X thread should execute, should not wait until Y(i) finish. how to do?

Comment: Now Y(i) calling as constructor but i need to call as another thread which run's parallel to X thread.

Comment: see,  when u do 
threadX.start();
threadY.start();
threadX and threadY run in parallel, this is answer to your first question i.e how to run threads in parallel.
Now passing values between threads is a little tricky part, we can use some shared resource to pass value like some third class shared by both the threads or use a queue... you can study, how to pass value between threads from internet

Comment: still any doubt?

Comment: Thanks... after go-through study material if i have any doubt ping you back. NOTE : If you have any document give me a link it will be helpful.

Comment: you can study from following link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_communication.htm

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted answer, below upvote button click on check sign to mark as accepted answer. Thanks